# Checkbox: jQuery required function

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

This is the code I'm using to display questions where users are required to select one or more checkboxes as answers:

```
$QA = '<label for="q'.$QID.'-'.$Value.'"><input type="checkbox" name="q'.$QID.'[]" id="q'.$QID.'-'.$Value.'" value="'.$Value.'"> '.$QA.'</label>';
```

And here's a typical display:

```
<li id="q8">
  <div class="Question">Which ones are countries?</div>
  <div class="Answer">
    <label for="q6-A"><input type="checkbox" name="q6[]" id="q6-A" value="A"> Texas</label>
    <label for="q6-B"><input type="checkbox" name="q6[]" id="q6-B" value="B"> Japan</label>
    <label for="q6-C"><input type="checkbox" name="q6[]" id="q6-C" value="C"> Spain</label>
  </div>
</li>
```

I want to modify the code so that the form won't submit unless a user selects at least one checkbox. Every script I've tried requires them to choose EVERY checkbox, but I just want to make sure they attempt to answer the question by choosing ANY ONE checkbox.

Someone suggested the following script:

```
$('input[type=checkbox][name=gender]')[0].attr('required', 'required');;
```

So I replaced "`name=gender`" with "`name=q6[]`", but that doesn't work. I'm guessing the brackets after q6 might be a problem, but if I remove the brackets from the code that drives the form - `name="q'.$QID.'[]"` - then the test is scored incorrectly on the results page.

Another problem is that this script requires a specific name, when similar multiple-choice checkbox questions on various tests can have various names.

Is there some way to modify this script so that it targets ALL questions that have checkboxes, requiring users to select at least one checkbox?

Comment: The attribute selector should use quotations around the value. `$('input[type=checkbox][name="q6[]"]')`. Quotations are only optional when the value [is a single word](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) (or identifier).

Comment: So I assume that means I can't use this jQuery function unless I can find a way to make my question-and-answer script work without the brackets, right?

Comment: No. Sorry. The brackets after `q6` don't need to be removed. They just need to be quoted within the selector to be understood as part of the elements' `name`s. `'[name="q6[]"]'`

Comment: Got it. I'll give that a try...

Comment: Wow, it still doesn't work. Maybe there's something wrong with my code I haven't figured out yet.

Comment: The `[0]` isn't necessary. `.attr(name, value)` will loop through the collection and apply to each element. (It also gives you a native `Element`, which won't have an `.attr()` method).

Comment: Wow, this script doesn't like me. ;) I removed [0], but it still displays "required" with every checkbox. This is what I'm now using: $('input[type=checkbox][name="q6[]"]').attr('required', 'required');;

Answer (score 0):

Try this out...

```
if(($('input[name="q6[]"]:checked') != undefined) && ($('input[name="q6[]"]:checked') != null)) {
console.log("true");
} else {
console.log("false");
}
```